# LR Transaction Log

Tags: loadrunner

Can LR create a transaction log for all the GETs/POSTs that was issued. One log record per GET/POST. Each record would have, at a minimum, the URL, date/time, response time, HTTP status, LR status, response length (bytes).  This would be similar to the JTL log in Jmeter.

I need this log to study the response times in detail -- e.g., if we suspect timeouts or high response times, I would like to go to this log to see when they occurred so I can correlate the slowness to something in the app or in the DB.

Can I get the transaction log from MDB? I don't have Microsoft Access so I can't check. Or can I get this from the eve file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a recommended practice to log all events because of the contention on the disk on the load generator.  Can you imagine hundreds, perhaps thousands of threads contending for write access to storage?  It become a drag anchor on your load generator performance.

I would point to two other sources of data for your analysis.

1. The HTTP access and Error logs on the target.  I am "assuming HTTP" with your GTE/POST references.   Be sure to enable the w3c ***time-taken*** value if it is not already a part of your log mode.  You can post process the logs in any way you wish, from microsoft Logparser to Splunk.  Having the time in both the request and the error logs will help you to understand the individual request and issues associated.  But, most importantly, this does not act as a drag on the load generator
2. The results MDB file.   This is a microsoft access formatted file used by the LR Analysis app, unless you have picked another taret (such as MS SQL Server).  The table you want to look into is the [Event Meter] table and it's related tables.   The relations are noted in the [METADATA] table for how to reconcile something which is readable.   Here is where you can pull times from user transactions, status, load generator name, script, etc....

The last item I would look to is the actual logs (with "Log on error" turned on).

3. Take a look in the file structure associated with your loadrunner results sets.  If you find no logs there (and the subdirectories after reconciliation), then you can find the logs on the load generators themselves. Be sure to make note of the load generator results directory in the scenario config in the controller

Comment: is there any place we can get response time along with timestamp, like we get in a JMeter JMX file. Its like a timeseries csv where you have every transaction along with its timing information. The LR Summary doesnt give enough information, we want to write our own analysis report on top of the raw data. I checked the output.mdb file and I dont see an "Event Meter" table inside it. The closest I have got to some raw data is the "sum_data" directory which has summary data for result graphs.

Comment: In the [Event Meter] table in the results database.  Time is milliseconds offset from start of test which is stored in a different table in Epoch time format.    Use the [Metadata] table to expose the relationships